# How should I format incoming JSON for UITableView with sections

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I'm writing an iOS app(my first one) and also am designing a feed from a database for events. The events are divided into logical groupings by topic. I want the end game with swiftyJSON to be a table with sections and section headers.  A possible JSON will look like but I'm willing to change it completely:

```
{ 
"events":[
  {"school events":
    [
      {"title":"event1school","start_date":"01/01/01"},
      {"title":"eventschool2","start_date":01/02/01"}
    ]
  },
  {"town events":
    [
      {"title":"event1school","start_date":"01/01/01"},
      {"title":"eventschool2","start_date":01/02/01"}
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

what I'm trying to accomplish is deliver a dictionary where they keys are the section headers and the rows are the array of infomration below the keys. I'm just new to iOS and have created a table from a JSON feed but haven't designed one from scratch.

Any advice appreciated.

I've gotten closer.

```
 self.swiftyJsonVar = JSON(jJson)

                for(key,object) in self.swiftyJsonVar["events"]{
                    print(key)
                    print(object)
                }
```

which prints

```
0
{
  "SCHOOLS" : [

  ]
}
```

It loops fine as well but I'm not sure how to get to the key and then the values after...I'm close...;)

Comment: that looks fine to me. you should be able to easily pull out keys as section headers from that.

Comment: you can use a convenient way http://www.jsoneditoronline.org to create a JSON and check respective Dictionary values

Comment: those property names aren't good. have a read of this https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml#Property_Name_Format

Comment: You can use Array of Dictionary to save the JSON responses. Like create a object class with value title and start_date, then create a dictionary with key "school events" and save the object class object as value. Then add this dictionary to an array. Iterate this unit all the response has been parsed, then use this array for setting your table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken your JSON in a local file and parsed in following way.
You can follow the same way to parse it.
I have taken a demo model object to keep the data

**Swift Version :**

My Model object looks like

import UIKit

```
class ReceipeBO: NSObject {


var headerValue : NSString!
var arrEvents   : NSArray!

init(headerValue:NSString, arrEvents:NSArray) {
    self.headerValue = headerValue;
    self.arrEvents = arrEvents;
}
```

}

So from the model object you can see, I am keeping the key in `headerValue` property and the event array of dictionaries in `arrEvents`

Here is the method where I am fetching from JSON response

```
func getLocalJsonData()
{
    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "json");

    let data = NSData.init(contentsOfFile: filePath!);

    var json : NSArray!
    var jsonTemp : NSDictionary = NSDictionary()

    do{
        jsonTemp = try  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary;
    }catch{

    }

    print("jsonTemp \(jsonTemp)");

    json = jsonTemp["events"] as! NSArray;

    print("json \(json)");

    let arrEvents = NSMutableArray();

    for dictTemp in json
    {
        let key = dictTemp.allKeys.first as! String;
        let arrValue = dictTemp[key] as! NSArray;

        let receipe = ReceipeBO(headerValue: key, arrEvents: arrValue);
        arrEvents.addObject(receipe);
    }

    print("evnts : \(arrEvents)");
```

}

**Now come to Objective C version :**

My Model object looks like

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ReceipeBO : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *headerValue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrEvents;


@end
```

Now in the similar manner explained above the `JSON` fetching function is as below

```
- (void)getLocalJsonData
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *jsonData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSDictionary *jsonTemp = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

    NSArray *json = jsonTemp[@"events"];

    NSMutableArray *arrEvents = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *dictTemp in json) {
        ReceipeBO *receipe = [[ReceipeBO alloc] init];

        NSString *key = [dictTemp.allKeys firstObject];
        receipe.headerValue = key;
        receipe.arrEvents = dictTemp[key];

        [arrEvents addObject:receipe];
    }

    //Access or fetching part

    for (ReceipeBO *objReceipe in arrEvents) {
        NSLog(@"Section header : %@", objReceipe.headerValue);

        for (NSDictionary *dictEvent in objReceipe.arrEvents) {
            NSLog(@"Event title %@ : Event start date %@", dictEvent[@"title"], dictEvent[@"start_date"]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
 Section header : school events Event title event1school : Event start
 date 01/01/01 Event title eventschool2 : Event start date 01/02/01
 Section header : town events Event title event1school : Event start
 date 01/01/01 Event title eventschool2 : Event start date 01/02/01
```

Hope it helps.

Happy coding ...

Comment: I will try this out however I think it may be a bit beyond my objective-C knowledge right now.

Comment: Are you coding it in Objective C ??

Comment: I have updated the answer for Objective C as well, check it. Let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for all the help but I've changed the format of the JSON so I'm going to repost as not to cloud this response...